# C# Skype Chat Bot

Tags: c#, process, bots, skype, chatbot

So, I'm making a simple chatbot, but when I try to attach it to skype by a button, it just crashes with an overflow, I was following a tutorial and did everything in the tutorial, but it just crashes when I press the attach button. Idk why since it seems to work for everyone else who uses the Skype4COM.dll

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void materialRaisedButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();

    }

    public Skype MySkype 
    { 
         get => MySkype; 
         set => MySkype = value; 
    }

    private void materialFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySkype.Attach(5, false);
        MessageBox.Show("Process Atached " + MySkype.CurrentUserHandle);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `MySkype` is a property and you are referring itself in getter and setter of it. The property should be defined as `public Skype MySkype{get;set;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving a StackOverflow exception because the `get` and `set` accessors reference the property rather than the private field you should have created; in essence, this causes an endless recursive loop that eventually causes the process to exhaust the available *RAM*.

your property should be something like this:

```
public Skype MySkype 
{ 
       get => _mySkype; 
       set => _mySkype = value; 
}
```

You *should* always aim to name private fields with an `_` prefix to distinguish them from properties.

---

Another approach would just be:

```
Skype MySkype { get; set; }
```

Comment: Oooooohhhh, Yeah im new lol, but i make these basic mistakes alot, learning from them tho, i just thought the tutorial would'nt leave me hanging like that and that i just forgot something somewhere.